# Debounce Functional Clock on AM335

Tags: arm, clock, cortex-a

What is the purpose of Debounce Functional clock on AM335x processor? In the technical reference they say: "The de-bounce clock is used for the de-bouncing cells". What cells? I am little confused with this.

Technical reference http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spruh73 page 4868

Comment: How about providing a link to the technical reference and a page number?

Comment: I provided, look now. :)

Comment: Hi, I would recommend you check out TI forums, they got employees paid to answer such question

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "debouncing", if not read this: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece473/lectures/debounce.pdf
It looks to me as if the AM335x has debouncing circuits built-in and these need a clock, this clock is called de-bounce clock. This is just me guessing so correct me please if I misunderstood.

Comment: @MathieuL Yes customer support exists but I would be surprised if they give much priority to questions from hobbyists/students compared to questions from big multinationals that buy tons of chips from them. That's just how it is unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, I got a lot of feedback from their forum for 1 of my student project. MultiNationals don't use Forums, they can use a direct line of support.

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't expect that, good to know though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it says "cells" it's simply referring to the I/O logic cells that are a part of the GPIO module. As stated in the reference (25.2.2) the GPIO modules require two clocks: the interface clock and the debounce clock.

If you go further down to section 25.3.2.1 it describes the debounce clock: "The debouncing clock is used for the debouncing sub-module logic (without the corresponding configuration registers). This module can sample the input line and filters the input level using a programmed delay." So, it does what you'd think (as the name describes), it filters out any glitches/false positives on a GPIO that's been assigned as an input.

Go a little further and in section 25.3.4.4 it describes the debouncing time and how to calculate it and enable it on a general purpose input.

And finally I found this https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/217327 where someone is talking about using the debounce feature.

Hope that helps clear up the mud some.